# Convert XML file to C# object with nested Lists

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, xml-deserialization

I have this XML file that I am trying to deserialize into a C# object, Closing Tabke tag wont show up but thats besides the point:

```
<Table>
<ConditionSets>
    <ConditionSet Name="All Coastal Exposures">
        <Condition Field="State" Values="GA,FL,NC,AL"/>
        <Condition Field="Client" Values="Default,ICAT,Olympus,SJIC"/>
        <Condition Field="Company" Values="GM,ACME,NWGF,DSFN,DSIC"/>
        <Condition Field="Product" Values="HO,FO"/>
        <Condition Field="Program" Values="*"/>
        <Condition Field="LineOfBusiness" Values="HO,FO,DF,IM"/>
        <Condition Field="TransactionType" Values="NB,RN,CH,RR,RW,RE"/>
        <Condition Field="TransactionMode" Values="Q,A"/>
        <Condition Field="UserType" Values="A,E"/>
        <Condition Field="Process" Values="Q,R,I"/>
        <Condition Field="Environment" Values="DEV,QA,UAT,PROD"/>
        <Condition Field="System" Values="BASE,SBIC,DSFM,NCIC"/>
        <Condition Field="Page" Values="Applicant,Completion"/>
        <Condition Field="Expression" Values="PolTransPolicy.BillingMethodCd='D'"/>
    </ConditionSet>
    <ConditionSet Name="Midwest Region">
        <Condition Field="State" Values="IL,IO,WI,MI,MN"/>
        <Condition Field="Client" Values="*"/>
        <Condition Field="Company" Values="GMIC,BMIC"/>
        <Condition Field="Product" Values="HO,FO,DF"/>
        <Condition Field="Program" Values="*"/>
        <Condition Field="LineOfBusiness" Values="HO,FO,DF,IM,PU"/>
        <Condition Field="TransactionType" Values="NB,RN,CH,RR,RW,RE"/>
        <Condition Field="TransactionMode" Values="Q,A"/>
        <Condition Field="UserType" Values="A,E"/>
        <Condition Field="Process" Values="Q,R,I"/>
        <Condition Field="Environment" Values="DEV,QA"/>
        <Condition Field="System" Values="BASE,GMIC,BMIC"/>
        <Condition Field="Page" Values="*"/>
        <Condition Field="Expression" Values="PolTransPolicy.BillingMethodCd='D'"/>
    </ConditionSet>
</ConditionSets>
```

I can't seem to get it to deserialize correctly because it is a list of lists. How would I set this up correctly in a C# object to deserialize?

This is the class im using to deserialize

```
[XmlRoot("Table")]
    public class Table
    {
        [XmlArray("ConditionSets")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ConditionSet")]
        public List<ConditionSet> ConditionSets { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConditionSet
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Conditions")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Condition")]
        public List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Condition
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Field")]
        public string Field { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Values")]
        public string Values { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Austin, welcome to *StackOverflow*. Could elaborate a bit on your question? What issue you are facing? Where you have the list within the list? Also, share the class that you are trying to deserialize into.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your XML.  You need a top level node like xml.  Then your missing your ConditionSets end node.

Once that is done, you can use this tool to convert your XML to C# deserialization code:

[Json2Charp](https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp)

Answer (score 0):

You must not use [XmlArray("Conditions")] [XmlArrayItem("Condition")] but simply

```
[XmlElement()] public List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
```

Your way would work if you have the condition lines contained within  .. .

Comment: This will not work since the tag is Condition and the variable names Conditions.  So either of the following will work 1) [XmlElement()] public List<Condition> Condition { get; set; } 2) [XmlElement("Condition")] public List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }